# Feriz rearrangement

Tags: hilbert-space, standard-model, group-theory, quarks, color-charge

For a tetraquark system $QQ\bar{Q}\bar{Q}$, with diquark-antiquark configuration, the color configuration can be $|6_{QQ}\otimes \bar{6}_{\bar{Q}\bar{Q}}\rangle_{1}$ or $|\bar{3}_{QQ}\otimes 3_{\bar{Q}\bar{Q}}\rangle_{1}$[arXiv:1907.05177](https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.05177)
, where 1 stands for color singlet. There is another a set of color representations of tetraquark: $|1_{Q\bar{Q}}\otimes 1_{Q\bar{Q}}\rangle_{1}$ and $|8_{Q\bar{Q}}\otimes 8_{Q\bar{Q}}\rangle_{1}$. The relations between two set of color representations are
\begin{aligned}
    |1_{Q\bar{Q}}\otimes 1_{Q\bar{Q}}\rangle &= \sqrt{\frac{1}{3}}|\bar{3}_{QQ}\times 3_{\bar{Q}\bar{Q}} + \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}|6_{QQ}\otimes\bar{6}_{\bar{Q}\bar{Q}}\rangle \\
    |8_{Q\bar{Q}}\otimes 8_{Q\bar{Q}}\rangle &= -\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}|\bar{3}_{QQ}\otimes 3_{\bar{Q}\bar{Q}}\rangle + \sqrt{\frac{1}{3}}|6_{QQ}\otimes\bar{6}_{\bar{Q}\bar{Q}}\rangle
\end{aligned}

I want to verify these relations by Feriz rearrangement: $\delta^{ad}\delta^{bc}=\frac{1}{3}\delta^{ad}\delta^{cd}+\frac{1}{2}\lambda_{n}^{ad}\lambda_{n}^{cd}$. However, How can I insert color indexes to this Feriz identity and from this relation, I can not see that square root factor for them.